# SVF file won't load properly in Forge Viewer from static folder

Tags: node.js, express, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm building a create-react-app application where I need to download, unzip, and serve files to be loaded into a (forge) viewer component. Running locally, this works fine. When I try to deploy to heroku, I get the following error:

> Error while processing SVF:
>   {"url":"https://mysterious-refuge-79338.herokuapp.com/viewables/744af950-6cb9-48c8-ac8c-dfec8f047166viewable/output/1/result.svf","exception":"Error:
>   End of Central Directory Record not found","stack":"Error: End of
>   Central Directory Record not found\n    at Y
>   (blob:https://mysterious-refuge-79338.herokuapp.com/50f3b2a8-61f8-4107-9055-ece0f92db53f:2:11694)\n
>   at N.e.r
>   (blob:https://mysterious-refuge-79338.herokuapp.com/50f3b2a8-61f8-4107-9055-ece0f92db53f:2:13124)\n
>   at V.loadManifest .... (The rest of the error is removed to get stack exchange to allow the post.)}

The files are being extracted into client/public/viewables, which is being served up by app:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Express will serve up production assets
    // like our main.js file, or main.css file!
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.use(express.static('client/public'));

    // Express will serve up the index.html file
    // if it doesn't recognize the route
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
  }
```

The path for the bubble.json file is then loaded in the Viewer:

```
function launchViewer(div, urn) {
getToken.accessToken.then((token) => {
    var options = {
        'document': urn,
        'env': 'AutodeskProduction',
        'accessToken': token.access_token,
        'api': 'derivativeV2',
      };

      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById(div));
        viewer.start();
        // var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');
      });
});
```

I'm guessing the issue is because of how the files are being served, or potentially how they're being extracted. As mentioned, this works when I run the application locally.

Answer (score 0):

The Document API doesn't support downloaded SVF currently since there is no manifest data available in the local env. You have to do the followings:

1. Change `env` from `AutodeskProduction` to `Local`
2. Remove `accessToken` and `api` parameter from the `options`
3. Use `Viewer3D#start` or `Viewer3D#loadModel` to load `https://mysterious-refuge-79338.herokuapp.com/viewables/744af950-6cb9-48c8-ac8c-dfec8f047166viewable/output/1/result.svf`

ref: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/blob/gh-pages/index.html
ref2: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewer-offline-net-mvc/blob/master/Autodesk/Views/Home/Index.cshtml